# dynamic slider value not working (ui.value)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to print the value of some dynamic sliders but the value it's not added to the inputs:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var N = 10;
    var initVal = 1;

    for (var id = 1; id <= N; id++) {

        var $newResult = $('<input/>', {
            type: 'text',
            id: 'result-' + id,
            class: 'sliderText',
            value: initVal
        });

        var $newSlider = $("<div/>", {
            id: 'slider-' + id,
            class: 'ui-slider'
        }).slider({
            range: 'min',
            min: initVal,
            max: N,
            value: initVal,
            step: 1,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $newResult.val(ui.value);  // neither works $( '#result-' + id )
            }
        });
        var $container = $("<div/>", {
            id: 'sliderContainer-' + id
        }).append($newResult).append($newSlider);

        $("#showSldr").append($container);
    }
});
```

It's seems there is something I don't see, maybe someone does :P

http://jsfiddle.net/fjs1pLv2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're reusing the `$newResult` variable you need to retain each reference in a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures):

```
  slide: (function($input) {
     return function(event, ui) {
         $input.val(ui.value);
     };
  })($newResult)
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/fjs1pLv2/2/**

Comment: It's odd to have to return the value since it used to work until I ended adding to much content and "features" to the animation :P

Comment: @ChazyChaz the value isn't being returned, the function is what is being returned.

Comment: Well I'm still learning about this. Should I do the same with all the sliders? Because I have others and are working fine without returning the function. Btw thanks for the help :)

Comment: @ChazyChaz It depends. Variable hoisting and closures are some of the tricky parts about learning JavaScript. Read this http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Comment: @ChazyChaz you can also simply wrap everything within the loop block in a closure http://jsfiddle.net/fjs1pLv2/3/

Comment: Hmmm yeah I prefer that one, it seems better and cleaner. Thanks for letting me know about it!